# div fixed inside div relative - both same size but fixed is bigger?

Tags: css

I have a div fixed inside a relative one.

my problem is, the div fixed is bigger than the other, but they have the same size:

```
<div id=all>

  <div id=top></div>

</div>
```

.

```
#all{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}

#top{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;
  position:fixed;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7yc0n21/

I need div top to be fixed.
what is wrong? Why div `top` is bigger than div `all`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The width of the fixed element is calculated in regard to the viewport width, whereas the one for the other is calculated in regard to the width of its parent element, which is `body` in this case.

And the width of body is different from the viewport width, because body gets a default margin and/or padding applied from the default stylesheet – so you are taking 80% of two *different* input values, and therefor the results are different as well.

Eliminate the default margin/padding for body, and the problem is gone:

```
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7yc0n21/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you specify

```
body {
   margin:0;
}
```

they will become the same width.

Also I think that is not what you want as fixed is calculated relative to viewport.

> **fixed**
>       Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1):

```
#all{
  width:80%;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}

#top{
 width:80%;
 height:100px;
 position:absolute;
 background:rgba(255,0,0,.5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give any element

```css
position: fixed
```

it makes the element relative to the viewport instead of it's offsetParent. Therefore, the width of div 'top' is calculated 80% based on the width of the viewport and not on the basis of its parent div 'all'. So, your inner div has greater width than outer one.